# Multicolor dip-painting techniques

Tags: manufacturing-engineering

I once saw on TV a factory dipping a product into a tank of paint and it magically emerged with a crisp pattern. (It was an Archery bow, and the pattern was army-style camouflage).

Was I deceived or is it actually possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like [hydrographic printing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrographics_(printing)). In short a design is printed onto a water soluble film and floated in a container of water to apply it to a surface.

It is generally used to apply complex and detailed patterns to curved and irregularly shaped surfaces as it conforms well to contours, especially as a cheaper and more repeatable alternative to hand painting.

Comment: [Here's an example](https://youtu.be/MhlRZ9gD0o4).